# Помогите разобраться с импортом в проекте Джанго

Tags: python, django, импорт, path, find

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не могу решить данную проблему: Только начинаю изучение Джанго и столкнулся с проблемой NoModuleFind , когда запускаю manage.py runserver.Все сделал как надо ,новое приложение внутри приложения Джанго добавил в список всех приложений в settings.py, написал функцию обработчик запроса в views.py , и использовал функцию path в urls.py По скриншоту все станет ясно.Заранее благодарю[image: Описание проблемы]

Comment: А зачем вы вообще импортируете views в urls?

Comment: from views import ...  или import views к чему там my_app

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev my_app это мое приложение созданно в проекте Джанго, и в пакете my_app находится модуль views в котором написана функция, ответ на запрос! Поэтому в модуле urls.py  когда я пишу метод path я импортирую свою функцию ответа с модуля views

Comment: @strawdog Добавил новые скриншоты , думаю так яснее будет !+  новый ответ у меня на комент

Comment: На будущее - код в вопросе должен быть в текстовом виде. и в подобном случае как у вас нужно показывать дерево каталогов.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо в основном файле urls.py (как я понял, в папке hello/hello) добавить сначала

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls import include
```

а затем

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('my_app/', include('my_app.urls')),
]
```

а не то, что вы написали

А потом в папке my_app создать urls.py и в него уже добавить

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
]
```